# Check if multiple classes/sessions are within same time frame

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an internal signup form for classes. I am working on a simple function that will check if the user has selected classes with conflicting schedules ( E.g. A class on from 1-2 p.m. as well as a class from 1-3 p.m. on the same day.)

Assuming that I'm using `mysqli` and fetching the classes the user has selected from a MySQL table with start and end `datetime` fields, what is the most efficient and/or effective way to compare the multiple classes in order to see if they conflict?

EDIT: Here's a sample table:

```
====================================================
|  id  |        start        |         end         | 
====================================================
|  1   | 2012-10-01 08:00:00 | 2012-10-01 08:00:00 |
====================================================
```

Obviously, there will be other data in the table (Like title, description, etc.), but I think I probably only need the data above to do comparisons. I will have an array with the `id` of every classes the user has signed up for.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I did search and did not see this asked before.

Comment: "the most efficient and/or effective way to compare" --- using php's `if`

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing your table structure and sample data.

Comment: @zerkms You mean a loop with an `if` statement?

Comment: @Robert Dundon: yep. Any problems with plain old `foreach` and `if`?

Comment: 1-select the classes using multi entry (like radio boxes)

2-add the whole courses into one query using ([in](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in))

3-check in php the timings using an array, the moment you set a time in array thats already there you should create a notification for that class

Comment: @Michael Added an example table.

Comment: @zerkms Nope, I just wanted to know the best way.

Comment: @Robert Dundon: the best way from which perspective? The cheapest one, the shortest one, ... When you don't have ANY solution - it makes no sense to find "the best", because you cannot compare them.

Comment: @zerkms s/the best/a working/%

Comment: @Robert Dundon: in the question you're asking about "the most efficient" (which is odd, as long as you have nothing to compare it with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your primary key is for this table. I'm fairly confident that mine is wrong for you, but it shouldn't matter for the purpose of your question.

```
-- student_id and class_id are foreign keys, not shown
create table times (
  student_id integer not null,
  class_id integer not null,
  primary key (student_id, class_id), 

  start_time timestamp not null,
  end_time timestamp not null
);
```

The first student has an overlap between classes 2 and 3.

```
insert into times values
(1, 1, '2012-09-01 08:00', '2012-09-01 08:55'),
(1, 2, '2012-09-01 10:00', '2012-09-01 11:55'),
(1, 3, '2012-09-01 11:45', '2012-09-01 12:45');
```

Second student, no overlaps.

```
insert into times values
(2, 1, '2012-09-01 08:00', '2012-09-01 08:55'),
(2, 2, '2012-09-01 10:00', '2012-09-01 11:55');
```

Third student has an overlap between classes 1 and 2.

```
insert into times values
(3, 1, '2012-09-01 08:00', '2012-09-01 10:00'),
(3, 2, '2012-09-01 09:55', '2012-09-01 11:55'),
(3, 3, '2012-09-01 12:00', '2012-09-01 12:55');
```

If your platform conformed to SQL-92, you could use the OVERLAPS operator. (If any dbms supported assertions, you could declare the tables in such a way that it wouldn't be possible to insert overlapping classes.)

```
select t1.*
from times t1
inner join times t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id
       and (t1.class_id <> t2.class_id and t1.start_time <> t2.start_time and t1.end_time <> t2.end_time )
       and (t1.start_time, t1.end_time) overlaps (t2.start_time, t2.end_time);
```

MySQL doesn't seem to support that, so you might use the equivalent definition from the SQL standards committee.

```
select t1.*
from times t1
inner join times t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id
       and (t1.class_id <> t2.class_id and t1.start_time <> t2.start_time and t1.end_time <> t2.end_time )
       and (
             (t1.start_time > t2.start_time and not (t1.start_time >= t2.end_time and t1.end_time >= t2.end_time))
             or
             (t2.start_time > t1.start_time and not (t2.start_time >= t1.end_time and t2.end_time >= t1.end_time))
             or
             (t1.start_time = t2.start_time and (t1.end_time <> t2.end_time or t1.end_time = t2.end_time))
       );
```

I'd expect the join conditions to give you good performance, as long as your tables are indexed carefully. In your case, you'd be selecting rows for a single student, which should be pretty selective. (I didn't do that in my example code.)